# NameError in Python Function

Tags: python, nameerror

I want to make a function that prints the Height of any of the 3 people.

```
def Height(Height):
    if Height in "John":
        return "100cm"
    elif Height in "George":
        return "120cm"
    elif Height in "Samuel":
        return "150cm"
    
print (Height(John))
```

I wanted it to print the height of John but instead it gives a NameError Saying That:

```
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

I know that I am Definitely doing something Wrong, But I can't figure it out.

Comment: `John` is being treated as variable instead of `string`. Why? There are no quotes. In this line, `print(Height(John))`. Also, don't keep the function name and its parameter name same, as the function cannot be called again in case of recursion, because the function name is now assigned to the `str` you passed as a parameter.

Comment: print (Height("John"))

Comment: Using "in" is not a good way to test for name equality. For example: `Height("Jo")` will incorrectly return John's height of "100cm". Use `if Height == "John":`, or, better still, use a dict that maps names to heights.

Comment: @Sam Thanks a Lot. I want "John" to be Treated as a Variable and not a string. How can i Do this?

Comment: @Sam1009 `John = "John"`. Define the variable before calling it.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the error as follows:

```
def height(person):
    if person == "John":
        return "100cm"
    elif person == "George":
        return "120cm"
    elif person == "Samuel":
        return "150cm"
    
print(height("John"))
```

However, I don't think using a function is the best way to do this task.  A better solution for storing this type of data is a dictionary.  This is how you would use a dictionary to achieve the same result:

```
heights = {
    "John": "100cm",
    "George": "120cm",
    "Samuel": "150cm"
}

print(heights["John"])
```